# Why is HTTP + Web Sockets not suitable as a messaging protocal?

Tags: websocket, message-queue, amqp, stomp

I've read that HTTP is not suitable as a messaging protocol in several places such as [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/protocols.html) in reference to RabbitMQ.

I assume that there's a technical reason for this and that it's not a mere opinion. I've looked through the AMQP [spec](https://www.rabbitmq.com/protocol.html) for example and can't see any reason why HTTP + Web Sockets can't work. In fact, something seems to be in the [works](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp-bindmap/amqp-wsb/v1.0/amqp-wsb-v1.0.html) for AMQP over Web Sockets. Furthermore, I've looked at the [STOMP](http://stomp.github.io/) protocol which does use HTTP + Web Sockets and can't see any significant limitations (other than a small performance hit).

What technical characteristic does HTTP + Web Sockets lack that makes it unsuitable as a messaging protocol?

UPDATE:
This is what I was looking for: [Crossbar.IO](http://crossbar.io/) - a WAMP message broker. I needed a message broker that I can easily connect to from a browser and have not been satisfied with RabbitMQ (over STOMP) or HiveMQ (MQTT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP is request/response based, what makes it difficult to work in a publisher/subscriber fashion. Basically, you can either poll the source of messages for new ones, or create another local endpoint where the other end push messages to you.

WebSocket is different. Despite of starting as a HTTP request, it switches straightaway to a persistent, full-duplex connection, where both end can push data. Basically, in this case HTTP is only used as protocol to negotiate the connection, once negotiated WebSocket uses its own protocol to transfer data.

UPDATE: We are clear that HTTP is not a messaging protocol, since it is request/response. WebSockets, although it allows pushing data from both ends, it is not a messaging protocol neither. It defines a way of framing data, but there are not defined semantic or grammar to subscribe to topics or any operation about messaging. For example [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) is an actual messaging protocol for websockets.

Comment: Sorry - I clarified my question. Is there something about using HTTP + Web Sockets that is technically lacking for messaging?

Comment: Nothing stops HTTP from being used a bad message protocol. The issue is that it's bad though. But anything that can receive and send can technically be used for messaging.

Comment: That's what I needed. Also, your answer helped me understand that "HTTP over Web Sockets" is the wrong way to think about what is really "Web Sockets initialized over HTTP."